# Ubuntu 19.04 hibernate/suspend

Tags: suspend, hibernate, resume

I want my notebook **(Lenovo-U31-70)** to be able hibernate/suspend and i can't do that. I think that i test all the basic solutions I find and nothing works...
I need help to understand what it can be.

I test all the ubuntu versions (16.10 - 19.04) and nothing works.
I hate to use windows but i need to use because of the hibernate function that windows has working.

I have dual-boot win10/ubuntu 19.04 with a 8GB ram and a swap with 11GB

So on this last 3 versions I have done the following.
manually test the option.

```
$ sudo systemctl hibernate
```

and of course doesn't work, the display gets black and the power button on, but some times restarts it self. So need pass to the configurations.

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
$ GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/sda7"
$ sudo update-grub
$ sudo reboot
```

After the above changes the result has some changes but not what i want.
The hibernation starts and our notebook shutdown our stays with the display black again.

When the shutdown ocours the restart doesn't resume but starts a new session.

I don't now what i can test more.

I have test other linux distros the Fedora and the hibernation occours without any configuration, but the resume it's the same starts a new one.

Comment: Hibernation isn't enabled by default - perhaps for a reason? - but suspension is and works fine in all systems I've tested.

Comment: suspend works on ubuntu 18.10. On 19.04 it also works but has a tendency to be stopped by incoming network traffic which is annoying.

Comment: Yes, the hibeernation comes disable, but why in Fedora some times works?

Answer (score 2):

For my Ubuntu 19.10 (eoan) `hibernate` package from `universe` works seamlessly,
when `pm-utils` fails.

Hardware: Dell Precision 7510

```
sudo apt-get install hibernate
sudo hibernate
```

**NOTE:** don't forget to save all your open documents before trying to hibernate for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: If you are using an encrypted swap partition, then please follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnableHibernateWithEncryptedSwap) on the Ubuntu help site.

I hope this will help someone, but I'm running Pop! OS / Ubuntu 19.04 (*update also works for 19.10 release*). In my setup I was able to hibernate using s2disk or pm-hibernate, but resume was failing. To fix this, as my system is booted up using UEFI instead of GRUB, I just had to reinstall the boot loader. To check if you are running UEFI use the following:

```
[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "Installed in UEFI mode" || echo "Installed in Legacy mode"
```

if in UEFI mode, then I followed this guide to reinstall the bootloader, it varies if you are using an nvme disk or sata disk:
https://support.system76.com/articles/bootloader/

The key is to run this command:

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
```

make sure that in your kernel boot options you specify the partition or UUID of where to resume from, eg something like this:

```
resume=UUID=ed8347ed-2eb4-40bc-bc77-cc53b987ed88
```

You can add this by either:

1. Running the command `sudo kernelstub -a "resume=UUID=ed8347ed-2eb4-40bc-bc77-cc53b987ed88"`
2. Editing the `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file and adding: 
   `resume=UUID=ed8347ed-2eb4-40bc-bc77-cc53b987ed88`

check your `/var/log/syslog` file for something like this:

```
Aug  4 22:26:42 pop-os /usr/bin/kernelstub[19639]: kernelstub           : DEBUG    kopts: root=UUID=b37019a8-91f5-445f-94c1-7359a49ed5df ro quiet loglevel=0 systemd.show_status=false resume=UUID=ed8347ed-2eb4-40bc-bc77-cc53b987ed88
```

If the resume is missing or wrong then you'll need to update your boot kernel again.

Comment: Thanks for this - got me most of the way there. A couple of notes: I tried adding /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume first, but this didn't do anything for me.  Have submitted an edit for the kernelstub command as the added '-' threw me at first.  Also possibly worth noting that that hibernate via systemctl worked, rather than pm-hibernate I was using at first.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just click the search or windows button and type sleep, you should see a pause icon. Click that and your computer is gonna go into hibernation

Comment: This will suspend, not hibernate.